# How to disable thermal policy for the icloud photo process?

Tags: catalina, photos

My Photo app has stopped updating the library for a while.

It seems to be hardware related. The temperature of the CPU is consistently around 72~73c even when there is no workload. The fan is always spinning.

This is what I see in the console log:

[image]

Here is the revelant text:

```
default 10:10:39.976213+1000    photolibraryd   downloadDidFinishForResourceDownloadTask: <private>, with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3072 "The operation was cancelled."\
default 10:10:39.976644+1000    photolibraryd   Failed to download resource [JPEGThumbnail for Ac5GUZYL1s6BtFjwSFFbjQAzeYg9#PrimarySync(1) (AUs8YCE9rVXyoHLyD/9qsCryrfRV - public.jpeg) file: <redacted>]. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3072 "The operation was cancelled."\
default 10:10:42.268364+1000    photolibraryd   Enqueuing CPL background download check (reason: start prefetching) at Thu Jun 25 10:40:42 2020\
default 10:10:56.926650+1000    dasd    502:com.apple.photolibraryd.backgroundjobservice.highpriority:5020C4:[\
    \{name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: \{Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [\{thermalLevel >= 2\}]\}\}\
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed\}\
```

It seems like, due to the thermal condition of my macbookpro, the icloud photo process has decided not to download any update.

However other icloud service seems to run fine and does not have this restriction.

Is it possible to disable this `ThermalPolicy`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more prudent to figure out why it's running so hot than to try bypass one of the safeguards employed when it's running so hot…?

Comment: I will send the unit back to repair soon but I have to wait at least a week. I want to get the photo app to work for now.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar but different problem, for some reason I dont think apple lists the specific thermal sensor values anymore when you type "sysctl -a | grep cpu" or grep thermal ... I read in some developer document that the values are enumerated to "text" not degrees C anymore?  Someone else posted they are able to get thermal values on "older" versions of the O/S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the error messages are still present in Console, the Photo app is able to sync changes in the Photo library in iCloud after upgrading maxOS to version 10.15.6 (19G2021).

I find out that the real reason is not the upgrade itself. Actually it is due to the fact that I disconnect my external monitor during the upgrade.

I typically use my MBP with both of its primary monitor and an external monitor turned on. It triggers the thermal throttling which stops the iCloud photo sync from happening.

Whenever I disconnect my external monitor, the icloud sync will succeed.